# SQL Database order more than one column in ASC

Tags: sql

first I read all posts before asked about this problem but didn't understand anyone then I'm trying to sort all columns from my table which all of them sorted in ascending if the column is number it's works successfully, but if the columns are varchar2 it's just sort one column and ignore others.

For example this code

```
SELECT first_name,last_name FROM employees
ORDER BY first_name , last_name DESC ;
```

[image: the output is] 
please explain to me.
Thanks.

Comment: Remember that your ORDER BY starts with sorting all _rows_ according to first_name. If several _rows_ have the same first_name value, this group is sorted according to last_name desc. (Take a look at row 4 and 5.)

Comment: I don't understand what order are you expecting it to be.

Comment: The sort type is specified for each part of the ORDER BY, your query is sorting as "first_name ASC, last_name DESC", if you want to order both parts as descending you need to specify it explicitly since default is ASC.... "ORDER BY first_name DESC, last_name DESC"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple column ORDER BY moves from left to right column.
Means first column will always sorted and second will be sorted in relation of first column

for example in below table persons with names **Muhammad** and **Ahmed** are sorted first and than by their second name which are **Khan** and **Ali**

```
| Firstname  | Lastname |
|------------|----------|
| Ahmed      | Ali      |
| Ahmed      | Khan     |
| Muhammad   | Ali      |
| Muhammad   | Khan     |
```

For reference please also take a look on [SQL Order By](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

ORDER BY works, of course, for both numerical and string datatypes. Numbers are sorted numerically, while strings are sorted alphabetically (according to the collation).

When sorting on two columns, the second one comes into play when there are ties on the first.

So this :

```
ORDER BY first_name , last_name DESC
```

Will first sorts alphabetically on column first name ; when several records have the same first name, then they will be sorted on the second column, in reverse alphabetical order.

In you case, I would tend to suspect that there are no duplicate first name, which is why the second column is not taken into account when sorting.

Answer (score 0):

In SQL "rows" are 'solid' so so first argument of order by is processed first then if multiple rows have same value on first column then the second argument is processed and so on.

what I think you seed is

```
order by last_name, first_name
```

so you have your table sorted first by surname then by name

Thake a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-order-by-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) on MS Sql Server documentation from beginning to 'best-practices' included to understand more (this sections are more or less general)

Answer (score 0):

Your query is not "ignoring" columns....
You may be thinking that `ORDER BY first_name , last_name DESC` must sort both columns in descending order, but it doesn't work that way...

The sort type (ASCENDING OR DESCENDING) is defined for each part of your ORDER BY clause, if it is not explicitly indicated it's default behavior is ASCENDING.

Then, you are ordering `ORDER BY first_name ASC, last_name DESC`

If you want both parts of your clause ordering descending `ORDER BY first_name DESC, last_name DESC`